# Ошибки при сборке проекта с зависимостями boost в cmake при помощи ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, cmake, boost

Пытаюсь собрать проект с зависимостями из boost.
При сборке с помощью студии выкидывает ошибку

`Ошибка LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_75.lib" task_13_1_45    F:\code\C++\tasks\build\task_13_1_45\LINK`

Мой ExternalProject.cmake :

```
    include( ExternalProject )

set( boost_URL "https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.75.0/boost_1_75_0.tar.bz2" )
set( boost_SHA1 "6109efd3bdd8b9220d7d85b5e125f7f28721b9a9" )
set( boost_INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/3rd_part )
set( boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${boost_INSTALL}/include)
set( boost_LIB_DIR ${boost_INSTALL}/libs )
set( BOOST_ROOT boost/src/external_boost )
set (EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS)
list (APPEND EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS
  -DBOOST_ROOT=${boost_INSTALL}
  -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON)

ExternalProject_Add( external_boost
        PREFIX boost
        URL ${boost_URL}
        URL_HASH SHA1=${boost_SHA1}
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND bootstrap.bat
            --with-libraries=program_options 
        --with-libraries=filesystem 
            BUILD_COMMAND
         b2 toolset=msvc --address-model=64 --link=static --variant=release stage install 
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    #INSTALL_DIR ${boost_INSTALL} 
    )
set( boost_LIBRARY_SUFFIX .lib )
include_directories(boost/src/external_boost) 
link_directories(boost/src/external_boost/stage/lib)


add_library( boost::program_options  STATIC IMPORTED )
set_property( TARGET boost::program_options PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${boost_LIB_DIR}/libboost_program_options.lib )
set_property( TARGET boost::program_options PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
add_dependencies( boost::program_options  external_boost )

add_library( boost::filesystem   STATIC IMPORTED )
set_property( TARGET boost::filesystem  PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${boost_LIB_DIR}/libboost_filesystem.lib )
set_property( TARGET boost::filesystem PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
add_dependencies( boost::filesystem  external_boost )
```

Пробовал просто собрать чужой пример у себя, например https://github.com/Sarcasm/cmake-superbuild
Под линуксом собралось все с первого раза. Под виндой начались проблемы. В самом файле с ExternalProject я заменил только bootstrap с .sh на .bat. Буст собрался удачно, судя по наличию всего необходимого в папке сборки. Но в конце вылезла ошибка:

```
    "F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (1) ->
"F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\ep_blah.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (3) ->
"F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\ep_boost.vcxproj" (целевой объект по умолчанию) (4) ->
(Целевой объект CustomBuild) ->
  libs\python\src\converter\builtin_converters.cpp(51): error C2440: return: невозможно преобразовать "const char *" в
"void *" [F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\ep_boost.vcxproj]
  libs\python\src\converter\builtin_converters.cpp(51): error C2440: return: невозможно преобразовать "const char *" в
"void *" [F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\ep_boost.vcxproj]
  F:\microsoft\visual_studio\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(240,5): error MSB8066: пользовательс
кая сборка для "F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\CMakeFiles\92a65a4cf8a9bae4c94159f881eb651c\ep_boos
t-configure.rule;F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\CMakeFiles\92a65a4cf8a9bae4c94159f881eb651c\ep_boo
st-build.rule;F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\CMakeFiles\92a65a4cf8a9bae4c94159f881eb651c\ep_boost-
install.rule;F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\CMakeFiles\40b72be63a4ad7ce8bafa596862227ba\ep_boost-c
omplete.rule;F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\CMakeFiles\8c349addd464f678079d435f2e386125\ep_boost.r
ule" завершила работу с кодом 1. [F:\code\C++\cmake-superbuild\cmake-superbuild\build\ep_boost.vcxproj]

    Предупреждений: 7
    Ошибок: 3
```

По идее в обоих случаях ошибка должна быть в путях. Но я не могу понять что и где идет не так.

Comment: А библиотека и проект собираются одним компилятором?

Comment: На машине в принципе только один компилятор стоит. И его поиск отдан cmake. Файл с ExternalProject просто подключается через include в основной CMakeLists. Так что компилятор должен быть один.

Comment: И еще вопрос: а буст точно собрался? Судя по логам у вас же ошибка...

Comment: Если задать пути в окружение(переменные среды), то буст можно спокойно использовать в других проектах. Именно тот, что собирался через суперсборку. Да и та либа, на которую он ругается присутствует там, где она должна быть.

Comment: Что-то я не пойму: а почему у вас INSTALL_DIR закоменчена? Вы вообще его устанавливаете?

Comment: Если INSTALL-DIR не указана, то он использует путь по умолчанию. Если бы установки не было бы, то в папке с бустом отсутствовали бы либы.

Comment: это, конечно ок, но вот только ничего, что вы не в дефолтной папке либы ищите?

Comment: Точно, спасибо, подправил пути, заработало как надо.

Comment: Проблема была в путях сборки зависимостей.

Comment: Рад был помочь.